# C++ Class constructor confusion

Tags: c++, string, class, g++

I have 2 files, Chrono.cpp and Chrono.h.

Chrono.h

```
class Appointment {
public:

    Appointment( Date d , string n ) ;
    Appointment() ;

    int get_day() const { return date.d; }
    int get_month() const { return date.m; }
    int get_year() const { return date.y; }
    string get_name() const { return name ; }

    Date date ;
    string name ;

} ;
```

Chrono.cpp

```
Appointment::Appointment( Date dd , string nn )
    : date( dd ) , name( nn ) 
{ 
    //if(!is_date(yy,mm,dd))throw Invalid(); 
}
```

I continue to get this error, or variations of saying it doesnt match the .h file.

```
Chrono.cpp:17:1: error: prototype for āChrono::Appointment::Appointment(Chrono::Date, String)ā does not match any in class āChrono::Appointmentā
Chrono.h:34:7: error: candidates are: Chrono::Appointment::Appointment(Chrono::Appointment&&)
Chrono.h:34:7: error:                 Chrono::Appointment::Appointment(const Chrono::Appointment&)
Chrono.h:42:2: error:                 Chrono::Appointment::Appointment(Chrono::Date, std::string)
Chrono.h:41:2: error:                 Chrono::Appointment::Appointment()
```

Both files have #include string and the .cpp file is in the std name space. I have also tried using std::string  in the header file. Nothing I have done has worked so far. Any help is appreciated. Also note that Date is defined elsewhere and is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled "String". In your code it says `string`, but in the error it says `String`.

Comment: The compiler is not recognizing it as std::string, so it outputs String. It is spelled correctly in the code

Comment: @Joshua: Please show us your *literal* line 17 in file `Chrono.cpp`.